# Show for $a,b \in \Bbb{C}$ that $\vert a - b \vert^2+\vert a + b \vert^2=2(\vert a \vert^2+\vert b \vert^2)$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

So for any complex numbers $a,b \in \Bbb{C}$ I need to show that

$$\vert a - b \vert^2+\vert a + b \vert^2=2(\vert a \vert^2+\vert b \vert^2)$$

So is it just a direct computation of setting $a=x+iy,b=w+iz$

Then The Left hand side becomes

\begin{align}
\vert a - b \vert^2+\vert a + b \vert^2 &= \vert (x-w)+i(y-z) \vert^2+ \vert (x+w) + (y+z)^2\vert\\
&=((x-w)+i(y-z))((x-w)-i(y-z)+((x+w)+i(y+z))((x-w)-i(y+z)\\ 
&=(x-w)^2+(y-z)^2+(x+w)^2+(y+z)^2\\
&=2(x^2+y^2+w^2+z^2)\\
&=2(\vert a \vert^2+\vert b \vert^2)
\end{align}

And for the geometric interpretation, Im having a touch time drawing it out to see what this means geometrically. Thanks for any tips and/or proof corrections, if my proof is incorrect?

Comment: This is the 'Parallelogram Identity'.  Draw the parallelogram with verticies $0,a , b ,a+b$. Sum of the squares of adjacent sides equals the sum of the squares of the diagonals.

Comment: so its a rectangle @geetha290krm also is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law

Comment: An alternate algebraic proof (that isn't *much* simpler, but avoids real/imaginary parts), you could also express $|z|^2 = z \cdot \overline{z}$, and expand the binomial sums and differences.

Comment: Or interpret $z=x+iy$ as the vector $(x,y)$, so $|z|^2=z\cdot z$, the dot product.